# gas: too many memory reference

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

When compiling the following instruction:

```
movl 4(%ebp), 8(%ebp)
```

I got: **too many memory reference**.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: it has too many memory references.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't movl from memory to memory allowed?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33794169) explains more about why this instruction-encoding limitation exists.  Also [Assembly: MOVing between two memory addresses](//stackoverflow.com/a/53470709) discusses details of picking a tmp register and using `movzx` loads for copying only a byte or word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number before the parenthesis is a byte offset (which causes a memory reference to occur), and you cannot have two of them with `movl`. You need to move the value temporarily to a register first.

```
movl 4(%ebp), %ecx
movl %ecx, 8(%ebp)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a legal instruction. For most instructions that reference memory you must move it to/from a register.

Answer (score 2):

`movl` doesn't to memory-memory moves, you have to go by way of a register (thus with two `movl` instructions).

Comment: thanks, but why this? is the cpu archtecture that limit this or something else?

Comment: Yes, it's a limitation in the CPU. MOVS is about the only memory-to-memory instruction.

Comment: Yeah, memory-to-memory just can't be implemented all that efficiently (non-x86 CPUs tend to have all instructions be just register to register, with load/store as the only register-to-memory ones).