# Compare two values from the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, cmp

I stuck
in my assembler code where I want to compare two values of the
stack.

x86, Syntax AT&T

```
cmpl -4(%ebp), 4(%ebp)
```

> Error: too many memory references for `cmp'

I think it is not possible to compare two values based on a multiplier and ebp. Any suggestions ?

Comment: In x86 it is impossible to use two memory operands with simple instructions like `CMP`. So copy/`MOV` one of the memory values to `EAX` and then compare the other to `EAX`.

Comment: The first few google hits for `"too many memory references for"` all have answers.  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531682/gas-too-many-memory-reference.  Most of them are about mov, not cmp, but MOVS and CMPS both exist.  Ira's answer makes a good point that CMP is different from wanting to add, for example, since you could do it another way.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare two values in memory using the CMPSD instruction.

Op wants to do something equivalent to:

```
  cmpl -4(%ebp), 4(%ebp)
```

He can do that by placing the addresses of the memory locations of interest in ESI and EDI respectively, and then using the [CMPSD memory-to-memory string-compare instruction](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-cmpsb.html):

```
  lea   -4(%ebp), %esi
  lea    4(%ebp), %edi
  cmpsd
```

(forgive my non-expert abuse of AT&T syntax).

That's different than anybody would do this in practice.  The other answers provided here (load a value into a register and compare) are much more practical.  If nothing else, those solutions only burn one register, and this hack burns two.

Lesson: in assembler, there's almost always more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @PeterCordes:  thanks for edit.